# extjs remove enter number placeholder from numeric filter on grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4

How can you remove the "enter number" placeholder in an extjs numeric filter of a grid. When Having a numeric input filter on a grd column, the numeric filter should not contain "enter a number" as default, it should contain a empty string. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
emptyCellText: ''
```

This should be set in your column definition. I am assuming by numberic filter you are implying that in the store or in the model of the data you are setting type: 'number

So for an example of this

```
{ text: 'Change', dataIndex: 'myindex', xtype: 'numbercolumn', format:'0.00', emptyCellText: '' }
```

By default it should be empty. I am not quite sure other than setting that is causing the enter a number, but I believe there has to be some mistake in your code this is not normal. The best way to post a question is by providing a code example, so people can have more to work with instead of just guessing.